# Is it ok to have multiple Durable functions in one function app?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-durable-functions

I have a function application that has a time trigger function, multiple HTTP trigger functions, and 2 durable functions. Each durable function consists of a Durable Functions HTTP starter, Durable Functions orchestrator, and 2 Durable Functions activity.

While trying to debug some issues, I ran into this https://stackoverflow.com/a/69352106/7537454 post that doesn't recommend  having 2 durable functions in the same function application.

Azure documentation doesn't have any information regarding this point. Is there any specific configuration to be done in this case?

It's been 2 years since that answer was posted, and I'd appreciate if someone could provide more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can totally have more than one orchestrator function in one Function App, no problem.

I think the answer that you linked may have misunderstood something.
They are talking about sharing the task hub, which would be an issue if you had two separate Function Apps using the same Storage account.
But even then you could just configure a different task hub name in both of those apps.

This is not an issue if it is e.g. two different orchestrator functions in one Function App.
The DurableTask runtime will route the messages it receives to the right orchestrators and activities.

Comment: Thank you very much. I actually have 2  orchestrators and  2 starters. Is it ok to have more than one starter? I also was thinking how would Azure figure out which starter to call if the starter url is pretty much the same:   "https://<some-app>.azurewebsites.net/api/orchestrators/Orchestrator1" and 
"https://<some-app>.azurewebsites.net/api/orchestrators/Orchestrator2"

Comment: Yes, absolutely.

Comment: Those URLs are different. It does not matter that the difference is small.